# What does msvc 6 throw when an integer divide by zero occurs?

Tags: exception, visual-c++-6

I have been doing a bit of experimenting, and have discovered that an exception is being thrown, when an integer divide by zero occurs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;


int main
(
    void 
)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 3;
        int y = 0;
        int z = x / y;
        cout << "Didn't throw or signal" << endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        cout << "Caught exception " << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Clearly it is not throwing a std::exception.   What else might it be throwing?

Comment: It doesn't throw a Divide-by-zero exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Windows structured exception, which has nothing to do with C++ - you would get the same exception if it were a C program.

Answer (score 1):

This article claims to have a way to convert a structured exception to a C++ exception using the [_set_se_translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298592(VS.60).aspx) function.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/seexception.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The result is undefined, you could use [__try / __except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19(VS.80).aspx) block to catch the error (structured exception handling).  However, why not simply check for the error before your division?

Answer (score 0):

In msvc6 you can catch it with catch(...) and rethrow it with throw; however since you can't detect exception type that way you're better off doing something else.