# The python exception vs C++ exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

With the following code, I get the "Gotcha!" with python.

```
try:
    x = 0
    y = 3/x
except Exception:
    # ZeroDivisionError
    print "Gotcha!"
```

I think this is the equivalent C++ code, but it can't catch the exeption.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 0;
  //float y = 3.0/x;
  int z = 0;

  try {
      z = 3 / x;
  } catch (std::exception) {
      std::cout << "Gotcha!";
  }

  std::cout << z;
}
```

```
Floating point exception
```

What went wrong?
How can I catch this exception?

Comment: Related: [How do I catch system-level exceptions in Linux C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618215/how-do-i-catch-system-level-exceptions-in-linux-c)

Comment: For a Windows specific perspective see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909967/what-does-msvc-6-throw-when-an-integer-divide-by-zero-occurs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, dividing by zero doesn't generate an exception; it causes undefined behaviour.

You *must* check you divisor before actually performing the division, as there is no way to know what will happen if you do actually evaluate a division expression with a zero divisor.