# How can I know the name of the exception in C++?

Tags: c++, python, exception

With Python, I could get the name of the exception easily as follows.

1. run the code, i.e. x = 3/0 to get the exception from python
2. "ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero" tells me this is ZeroDivisionError
3. Modify the code i.e. try: x=3/0 except ZeroDivisionError: DO something

Is there any similar way to find the exception name with C++?

When I run the x = 3/0, the compiled binary just throws 'Floating point exception', which is not so useful compared to python.

Comment: You shouldn't divide by zero ;)

Comment: Indeed; division by zero will invoke undefined behaviour. On Posix platforms it will raise SIGFPE rather than throwing a C++ exception, since that is the behaviour defined by Posix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The python exception vs C++ exception handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113904/the-python-exception-vs-c-exception-handling)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can't easily ask for the name of the exception, if the exception derives from `std::exception` you can find out the specified reason it was shown with `what()`:

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (const std::exception &exc)
{
    std::err << exc.what() << std::endl;
}
```

On a side note, dividing by 0 is not guaranteed to raise a C++ exception (I think the MS platforms may do that but you won't get that on Linux).

Comment: Win32 platforms can raise a SEH `EXCEPTION_FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO` exception (0xC000008E). There's also an integer variant, `EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO == 0xC0000094`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the name of the exception class, you could use RTTI. However, the vast majority of C++ code will throw an exception derived from std::exception.

However, all you get is the exception data contained in std::exception::what, and you can get the name of the exception class from RTTI and catch that explicitly if you need more information (and it contains more information).

Answer (score 1):

For most exceptions if you have the RTTI option set in your compiler, you can do:

```
catch(std::exception & e)
{
    cout << typeid(e).name();
}
```

Unfortunately the exception thrown by a divide by zero does not derive from std::exception, so this trick will not work.

Comment: Also note that the format of typeid(foo).name() is implementation-defined; on some platforms, it's mangled.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a debugging issue, you may be able to set your compiler to break when it hits an exception, which can be infinitely useful.